to get all the following distinct values in pyspark
I have a table with data in time order



order_id
order_status
status
modify_time




1
IN_TRANSIT
warehouse_in
2024-06-22T21:53:04


1
IN_TRANSIT
warehouse_out
2024-06-23T02:06:36


1
IN_TRANSIT
outbound_success
2024-06-23T02:28:03


1
CUSTOMS_RELEASED
airline
2024-06-23T02:29:39


1
READY_FOR_PICKUP
in_office
2024-06-23T22:35:40


1
DELIVERED
pickedup
2024-06-25T15:46:19


2
IN_TRANSIT
warehouse_in
2024-06-25T17:46:26


2
DELIVERED
pickedup
2024-06-25T18:00:00



I need to get a list of unique values of order_status ​​that are after the current status. For example the output in the column "output".



order_id
order_status
status
modify_time
output_nondistinct_values
output_distinct_values




1
IN_TRANSIT
warehouse_in
2024-06-22T21:53:04
IN_TRANSIT,IN_TRANSIT,CUSTOMS_RELEASED,READY_FOR_PICKUP,DELIVERED
IN_TRANSIT,CUSTOMS_RELEASED,READY_FOR_PICKUP,DELIVERED


1
IN_TRANSIT
warehouse_out
2024-06-23T02:06:36
IN_TRANSIT,CUSTOMS_RELEASED,READY_FOR_PICKUP,DELIVERED
IN_TRANSIT,CUSTOMS_RELEASED,READY_FOR_PICKUP,DELIVERED


1
IN_TRANSIT
outbound_success
2024-06-23T02:28:03
CUSTOMS_RELEASED,READY_FOR_PICKUP,DELIVERED
CUSTOMS_RELEASED,READY_FOR_PICKUP,DELIVERED


1
CUSTOMS_RELEASED
airline
2024-06-23T02:29:39
READY_FOR_PICKUP,DELIVERED
READY_FOR_PICKUP,DELIVERED


1
READY_FOR_PICKUP
in_office
2024-06-23T22:35:40
DELIVERED
DELIVERED


1
DELIVERED
pickedup
2024-06-25T15:46:19




2
IN_TRANSIT
warehouse_in
2024-06-25T17:46:26
DELIVERED
DELIVERED


2
DELIVERED
pickedup
2024-06-25T18:00:00





I thought it may work somehow with LAST_VALUE but it may show only one value and i need the list.

from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn('modify_time', F.to_timestamp('modify_time'))
window_spec = Window.partitionBy('order_id').orderBy('modify_time').\
              rowsBetween(Window.currentRow + 1,Window.unboundedFollowing)
df = df.withColumn('output_nondistinct_values',F.collect_list('order_status').over(window_spec)).\
              withColumn('output_distinct_values',F.collect_set('order_status').over(window_spec))
df_op = df.select('order_id', 'order_status', 'status', 'modify_time', 'output_nondistinct_values', 'output_distinct_values')
df_op.display()



Thanks a lot! Didn't know about collect_set and collect_list functions, very useful
